# Listen to onClick with Enzyme

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I want to assert that when a disabled button has been clicked, its `onClick` event is not fired. How do I do this with enzyme? Please see the sample code below. Thanks!

**sampleButton.jsx:**

```
import React from 'react';

const SampleButton = () => (
  <button
    disabled={true}
    onClick={() => console.log('You clicked me!')}
    test-attr="button"
    type="button"
  >
    Click Me
  </button>
);

export default SampleButton;
```

**sampleButton.test.jsx:**

```
import React from 'react';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import SampleButton from './sampleButton';

test('cannot click button if disabled', () => {
  const wrapper = shallow(<SampleButton />);
  const button = wrapper.find('[test-attr="button"]');
  button.simulate('click');
  // assert that `onClick` has not been fired
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not really necessary to test this. The `disabled` prop is part of the underlying HTML, so by testing it you're just testing that the HTML `button` works (which you can trust that it does). A better test might be to check that the `disabled` prop is set to `true` under the conditions you're trying to test.

That said, one way to do this is by injecting your `onClick` into `SampleButton` via `props`, like this:

```
const SampleButton = ({ onClick }) => (
  <button
    disabled={true}
    onClick={onClick}
    test-attr="button"
    type="button"
  >
    Click Me
  </button>
);
```

Then you can test it like this:

```
test('cannot click button if disabled', () => {
  // Set up a mock function that allows you to make assertions
  const mockOnClick = jest.fn();
  // Pass it into SampleButton
  const wrapper = shallow(<SampleButton onClick={mockOnClick} />);
  const button = wrapper.find('[test-attr="button"]');
  button.simulate('click');
  // Make assertions
  expect(mockOnClick).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

Comment: note, `simulate` doesn't honor the `disabled` attribute. For further details, see [here](https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/issues/386).

Comment: I hadn't seen that issue! I did some testing... interestingly, it looks like it's only an issue with `shallow`: https://codesandbox.io/s/enzyme-disabled-button-test-mgs46 (see tests for `counter.test.js`)